# Maven command mvn javadoc:jar downloads log4j-1.2.12

Tags: maven, log4j, javadoc

When executing the Maven command `mvn javadoc:jar`, it downloads log4j-1.2.12.jar, which contains vulnerabilities. The projects in scope do not have any dependency on log4j, nor do we have a plugin to generate JavaDocs.

Our Maven version is 3.6.0.

Any suggestions on how to proceed to get rid of the log4j?

Comment: First why even using Maven 3.6.0... second which maven-javadoc-plugin do you use? Why calling the goal? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ Also check if you have it as transitive dependency somewhere... check via `mvn dependency:tree` because javadoc plugin does not has a dependency to log4j...

Comment: Which maven do you suggest to use, at the moment it is 3.9.4.             
 As I mentioned log4j is only donwloaded when mvn javadoc:jar executed and it does not relation to plug-in or dependencies mentioned in the pom-file.                                                                                                                              dependency:tree does not show any log4j dependency.

Comment: Even upgrading to maven 3.9.4  still keeps downloading log4j files.

Comment: Confirmed: it happens even with maven 3.9.4 and even with a dummy pom containing no dependency and no explicit parent.  I used default maven cfg.  However it downloads only `log4j-1.2.12.pom` , not the jar, so it shoud be safe.  Strange but safe.

Comment: It's a very old bug, never fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-726

Comment: @Pino so no fix for this issue, so the only solution to is to not generate javadoc to our release artifacts.

Comment: As I said the jar is not downloaded, so it should be safe.  However I have no solution, sorry.

Comment: I can confirm that it now only dowloads following 3 files:                                           
 log4j-1.2.12.pom, log4j-1.2.12.pom.sha1, _remote.repositories.

Comment: So as long the jar-files is no longer generated I hope our environments are safe.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve a project's or plugin's dependencies Maven:

1. Creates a huge graph with all dependencies and transitive dependencies. To do this it must recursively download the POM files of each of them,
2. Chooses the dependencies that it will use. Log4j 1.x is not part of them,
3. Uses those dependencies at runtime.

In your case `log4j:log4j:1.2.12` gets to phase one, but the JAR is **not** downloaded and **not** used.

**Remark:** The vulnerabilities of Log4j 1.x are very peripheral and difficult to trigger. Even **if** Log4j 1.x was used in your build, you'll need to provide a very specific configuration (e.g. log to a database) to be vulnerable.

In `maven-javadoc-plugin` there are vulnerable dependencies that have a bigger chance of being used, e.g. the dependencies of [`doxia-site-renderer`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.11.1). Obviously without further inspection there is not way to tell if they apply to the plugin.